# How to display a list of data from a map ? - flutter firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, snapshot

I am building an event management app. When the user buys a ticket, the ticket details are being saved in the DB like this.
`Users -> (Current User ID) -> (map)bookedEvents -> eventId -> [event details]`

[image]

I managed to display data of one specific event when I give one of the Event IDs as a static String like this.

```
StreamBuilder(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('users')
              .doc(_uid)
              .snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return Text("Loading");
            }
            var userDocument = snapshot.data;
            return Text(
              userDocument["bookedEvents"]["KFXvCj63y7GTjQcMKfVy"]
                  ["eventName"],
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20),
            );
          }),
```

But I want to display all the Event Names in a list. Could I know how? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try something like that:

```
var userDocument = snapshot.data;

final List<Widget> children = [];

userDocument['bookedEvents'].forEach((key, value) { 
children.add(Text(value['eventName'])); });   
 
return Column(children: children); // or Row(children: children); or ListView(children: children);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do I have to do this inside the StreamBuilder?

Comment: Yes! Just replace starting with the line "var userDocument = snapshot.data;" until "retrun Text(...);" with my code!

Comment: When I try to implement this code inside the streambuilder, `forEach` shows an error. `Function expressions can't be named.  Try removing the name, or moving the function expression to a function declaration statement.`

Comment: Could I please know how to solve that error? I really appreciate your time and effort.

Comment: Sorry I miss-typed: replace the corresponding line with this:   userDocument['bookedEvents'].forEach((key, value) {
    children.add(Text(value['eventName']));
  });